# Error: Input [<shapely.geometry.point.Point>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point>] is the wrong shape for a LineString

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I'm trying to create a linestring out of a dataframe of latitudes and longitudes.

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(linkdf.lon, linkdf.lat)]
linkgdf = GeoDataFrame(linkdf, geometry=geometry)
linkdf_line = linkgdf.groupby(['linkId'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
linkdf_line = linkdf_line.apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
linkgdf_line = GeoDataFrame(linkdf_line, geometry='geometry')
```

Where linkdf is just a dataframe of latitudes and longitudes:
 [image: linkdf]

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Input [<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000002AB98131AC8>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000002AB98131198>] is the wrong shape for a LineString
```

What is really confusing me is that this seems to work in a jupyter notebook, but not running my python script in terminal.

Comment: Is there a reason you are converting each coordinate to a shapely Point() first rather than just going straight to a LineString?

Comment: no - I assumed LineString would need shapely Points instead of just passing it strings of points... let me see what works

Comment: Well, LineString should take either Points or coordinate tuples (or even a mix of both), but given your error I might try to pass in tuples directly--may fix or shed more light on the issue.

Comment: Ok, that seemed to work! Thank you!

Comment: Cool. You should add the answer (whatever you did) to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing lat / lon directly as a string tuple fixed the problem - didn't even need to convert to shapely point to turn into LineString

```
geometry = [xy for xy in zip(linkdf.lon, linkdf.lat)]
linkdf['geometry'] = geometry
linkdf_line = linkdf.groupby(['linkId'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
linkdf_line = linkdf_line.apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
linkgdf_line = GeoDataFrame(linkdf_line, geometry='geometry')
```